# Android studio suggests a simplify If statement syntax

Tags: java, android

Using this snippet code in an android project

```
 if (null == f_Panel_2) {
     mTowPan = false;
} else {
    mTowPan = true;
}
```

Android studio suggests a simplify if which

```
mTowPan = null != f_Panel_2;
```

and it works fine like the above one.

Can anyone explain How this works?

Comment: Maybe this is easier for you? `mTowPan = (null != f_Panel_2);`

Comment: Rather it would be easier to understand `mTowPane = !(null == f_Panel_2)` ... but for FSM sake it's logic basics and you are student of computer and information technology

Comment: thanks bro i get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null != f_panel_2` works because it evaluates to `true` or `false` depending upon if `f_panel_2` is null. Since you're assigning to `mTowPan` the value if the `if` statement is `true` or `false`, the syntax tree can be reduced to `mTowPan = f_panel_2 != null`

So, `mTowPan` is `true` if `f_panel_2` is not `null` else it is assigned value of `false`.